# Cannot access server REST API from integrated browser using jquery

Tags: java, jquery, cors, jersey

I am having a Jersey REST Service application running on a server. This application should be accessed from a desktop application with an integrated browser, for which I can define HTML pages with Javascript. Thus, the client code is executed locally with the origin d://. When I am running my Jersey Application on my local computer with a localhost address, everything runs perfectly fine. However, when I deploy the Jersey application on the server and try to access it from my desktop application, an error is returned with the status 0. Using Postman on my local computer, I have no issue accessing the jersey appliation on the server. However, when I am checking my logs, I see, that no preflight request is sent via Postman (no request with origin != null). 
Based on this problem I am guessing, that this is related to CORS. I added a CORS filter to my Jersey application but it is still not working. The server is not registering any incoming requests from my Desktop application. Has anybody an idea what I am missing? Thank you for the support.
My code for querying the data in the Desktop application:

```
var ajaxObj = {
        type: "POST", 
        url: jerseyApplicationUrl,
        crossDomain: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(inputFile),  
        contentType:"application/json",
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Error "+ textStatus +" " + jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders() + " " + errorThrown+ " "+ jqXHR.status+" " +jqXHR.responseText);
        //Output: Error error 0 undefined
        },
        success: function(data) { 
                console.log("Server returns success for data query with result ");
        },
        complete: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
            //console.log( XMLHttpRequest.getAllResponseHeaders() );
        }, 
        dataType: "json" //request JSON 
    };
    $.ajax(ajaxObj);
```

My CORS class in the Jersey Application:

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class CorsFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {
    // If it's a preflight request, we abort the request with 
    // a 200 status, and the CORS headers are added in the
    // response filter method below.
    if (isPreflightRequest(request)) {
        request.abortWith(Response.ok().build());
        return;
    }
}

/**
 * A preflight request is an OPTIONS request
 * with an Origin header.
 */
private static boolean isPreflightRequest(ContainerRequestContext request) {
    return request.getHeaderString("Origin") != null
            && request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS");
}

/**
 * Method for ContainerResponseFilter.
 */
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request, ContainerResponseContext response)
        throws IOException {
    boolean debug = MtcServiceApplication.getInstance()!=null?MtcServiceApplication.getInstance().isDebug():false;
    // if there is no Origin header, then it is not a
    // cross origin request. We don't do anything.
    if (request.getHeaderString("Origin") == null) {
        return;
    }

    // If it is a preflight request, then we add all
    // the CORS headers here.
    if (isPreflightRequest(request)) {
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            // Whatever other non-standard/safe headers (see list above) 
            // you want the client to be able to send to the server,
            // put it in this list. And remove the ones you don't want.
            "X-Requested-With, Authorization, " +
            "Accept-Version, Content-MD5, CSRF-Token, Content-Type");
    }
    
    // Cross origin requests can be either simple requests
    // or preflight request. We need to add this header
    // to both type of requests. Only preflight requests
    // need the previously added headers.
    response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
}
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `errorThrown`?

Comment: Unfortunately, errorThrown is undefined.

Comment: I suggest you step into `$.ajax(ajaxObj)` and see exactly what's happening. (Use the uncompressed version of jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem. The reason the query did not reach the server was, that the integrated browser in my desktop application uses an old encryption protocol which was blocked by the server. It requires TLSv1. That is also the reason why it worked fine in my test file because there I was using an up-to-date browser which used a new encryption protocol. Now I have to find a solution for my server properties without endangering my server.